# Accessing method in main class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have class with name of `ArticleDialogBox`
in constructor of that i create the anonymous class that implement some interface i want to access a method with name of `articleSelected` from `ArticleDialogBox` how is possible to access that?

```
export class ArticleDialogBox {
private articlesListBox: ListBox = new ListBox();
private titleTextBox: TextBox = new TextBox();
private saveButton: Button = new Button();

constructor() {
    this.articlesListBox.addEventHandler(new class implements EventHandler {
        handle(): void {
           //how can i  access a method in ArticleDialogBox.articleSelected(); 
        }
    });

  }
 articleSelected(): void {
    this.titleTextBox.setContent(this.articlesListBox.getSelection());
    this.saveButton.setEnabled(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical solution would be something like this:

```js
constructor() {
    const _self = this;
    this.articlesListBox.addEventHandler(new class implements EventHandler {
        handle(): void {
           _self.articleSelected(); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should use a syntax-correct word. Please use `something` rather than `smth`.